# java apache cfx soap namespace trimmed to 4 characters

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I created SOAP service on Spring Boot and Apache Cfx. I need to get a namespace of 7 characters, but it is cut off to 4

For example, I write the following code

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://example.com/testNs", name = "SoapService")
@Features(features = "org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
public interface SoapService {
    @WebResult(name = "ResultMsg")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "Wrapper")
    ResultMsg soapReq(@WebParam(name = "requestId", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/testNs") String requestId,
                      @WebParam(name = "smsFlag", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/testNs") String status);
}
```

Based on this code, a wsdl is generated:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/testNs" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="SoapService" targetNamespace="http://example.com/testNs">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/testNs" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/testNs" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="Wrapper" type="tns:Wrapper"/>
<xs:element name="ConnectorOutput" type="tns:ConnectorOutput"/>
<xs:complexType name="Wrapper">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="requestId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ConnectorOutput">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResultMsg" type="tns:resultMsg"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="resultMsg">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="resultCode" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="resultMessage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="soapReqResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:ConnectorOutput" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="soapReq">
<wsdl:part element="tns:Wrapper" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SoapService">
<wsdl:operation name="soapReq">
<wsdl:input message="tns:soapReq" name="soapReq"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:soapReqResponse" name="soapReqResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SoapServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SoapService">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="soapReq">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:soapRequest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="soapReq">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="soapReqResponse">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SoapService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:SoapServiceSoapBinding" name="SoapPort">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/soap/soapRequest"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Correct xml generated based on this wsdl that the server will accept

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://example.com/testNs">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <test:Wrapper>
            <test:requestId>0000228610</test:requestId>
            <test:status>1</test:status>
        </test:Wrapper>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:testNs="http://example.com/testNs">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <testNs:Wrapper>
            <testNs:requestId>0000228610</testNs:requestId>
            <testNs:status>1</testNs:status>
        </testNs:Wrapper>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please tell me how to make the namespace be more than 4 characters?

Comment: Can you better explain the problem ?

Comment: I have corrected the question